# Should I enable automatic Wordpress updates for "dev"?

Tags: wordpress

That I know the three auto-update options are:

- auto_update_core_dev
- auto_update_core_mino
- auto_update_core_major

My doubt is about the `auto_update_core_dev` is it some kind of "developer" updates with beta features, something reserved for developers to test if news things works or not?

Answer (score 0):

This was near impossible for me to find out from the documentation, but digging through the code, it would appear that `auto_update_core_dev` allows for automatic updates to versions containing a dash (`-`).

```
$current_is_development_version = (bool) strpos( $wp_version, '-' );
```

https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/class-core-upgrader.php#L279

Further down, you will also see a comment with some examples of versions that are considered part of the dev branch.

```
// 3: 3.7-alpha-25000 -> 3.7-alpha-25678 -> 3.7-beta1 -> 3.7-beta2.
if ( $current_is_development_version ) {
```

https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/class-core-upgrader.php#L340

I'm going to assume you'd want that turned off.